# Usage of both "Order Deny,Allow" and "RewriteRule"

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have read [Deny from all in subdirectory htaccess not overriding file rules in root htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17611770/deny-from-all-in-subdirectory-htaccess-not-overriding-file-rules-in-root-htacces) and [htaccess "order" Deny, Allow, Deny](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9943042/htaccess-order-deny-allow-deny/10078317#10078317) but I don't see why this does not work:

```
Order Deny,Allow
<Files articles/*.*>
Deny from all
</Files>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
```

The file `example.com/articles/test.txt` is still viewable, whereas it should not. This shows that the `articles/*.*` rule does not work.

Where is the problem in my `.htaccess`?

---

Note: Since I have Apache 2.4, I have tried:

```
<Files "articles/*.*">
Require all denied
</Files>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
```

but the problem is still there.

Comment: confirm your Apache version? You can use `<Files test.txt>
Order allow, deny
Deny from all
</ Files>`

Comment: @Pandurang I'd like to do everything from a unique `/.htaccess`, and not a htaccess in each subdirectory like this: `/articles/.htaccess`, etc.

Comment: Refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11728976/how-to-deny-access-to-a-file-in-htaccess

Comment: @Pandurang I have tried similar things (see my last edit a few seconds ago), but it does not work (maybe because of `RewriteRule` / `<Files>` mix?)

Comment: for testing, purpose disable other rewrite rules. Also try with `RewriteRule ^/?/articles/$ - [F,L]`.

Comment: @Pandurang maybe the problem comes from this: can we use a subdirectory path in Files like this:  `<Files subdir/*.*>`?

Comment: `<Files subdir/*.*>` is not working at my site . I tested with `RewriteRule ^/articles/?$ - [F,L] `and working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with below rewrite rule.

```
RewriteRule articles/.*$ - [F]
```

This uses the [F|forbidden](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_f) flag.

Note:

> When using [F], an [L] is implied - that is, the response is returned immediately, and no further rules are evaluated.